# NTFS: Multiple $DATA attributes, with the same name

Tags: c++, windows, ntfs

I am aware that NTFS supports ADS, which means multiple data streams, while each one has a different name. However, I am currently trying to parse my volume and a specific MFT record owns 3 **unnamed**, unique (different in size and data runs) data streams.
The file is filled with 256mb of "~" (single character), and all the data streams were found in related MFT Records which were collected the attributes list attribute. In a normal "flow", I would parse the data runs of the desired stream, and read from the desired offset the desired length. How am I supposed to deal with this situation? (== read the file's content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Alternate Data Streams (ADS) should have an unique name. It's right that you have several attributes with type `$DATA`, but it should have different names. E.g. if some file *multiple.txt* has ADS with name *overhere* it should have the following `$DATA` attributes. Sample from [here](https://wiki.sleuthkit.org/index.php?title=NTFS_Implementation_Notes):

```
Type: $DATA (128-1)   Name: $Data      Resident   size: 15
Type: $DATA (128-5)   Name: overhere   Resident   size: 26
```

The full name of 128-1 is *multiple.txt* and the full name of 128-5 is *multiple.txt:overhere*

Other unnamed attributes typically are:

```
Type: $STANDARD_INFORMATION (16-0)   Name: N/A   Resident   size: 72
Type: $FILE_NAME (48-2)              Name: N/A   Resident   size: 90
Type: $OBJECT_ID (64-3)              Name: N/A   Resident   size: 16
```

Try the [istat](http://www.sleuthkit.org/sleuthkit/man/istat.html) Sleuthkit utility for your MFT record:

```
istat -f ntfs <SourceName> <ID>
```

With the [other tools from collection](https://wiki.sleuthkit.org/index.php?title=TSK_Tool_Overview) you will be able to copy the content of these data streams.

It's an open source, so you could check the details of [NTFS](https://github.com/sleuthkit/sleuthkit/blob/develop/tsk/fs/ntfs.c) implementation and to investigate how the data retrieved from the `$DATA`.